# Redirect using JS

Tags: javascript, php, submit

Here is my code, I want add.php to open in the current tab not open a new window all together.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add Record" onclick="addrecord()">
          <script>
               function addrecord() {
                    window.open("add.php", "Add Record", "_self");
               }
          </script>
```

Comment: due to window.open .always it will open in new window..u jst use window.location='http://someUrl.com'; or location.href='http//eg.com';

Comment: if you want to open form then try calling AJAX and replace HTML of current window.

Comment: Redirect the page. check my answer.

Comment: @Tye Lucas, Accept answer if that solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you should redirect the page not opening a new window. Try below snippet.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add Record" onclick="addrecord()">

    <script type="text/javascript">
                   function addrecord() {
                        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
                   }
    </script>
```

Comment: sadly the above code does nothing =/

Comment: Try this onclick="window.location = "http://www.google.com";"> if it works then put the snippet in the head tag

Comment: I solved my own problem last night after going to bed, it hit me like a train, and it works brilliantly!

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['addentry'])) {
                
                    header('Location: ./add.php');  
                          
                    }  ?>

Comment: glad to hear. let me know if you need any thing to accept the answer

Comment: <div class="addentrydiv">
                    
                <input type="submit" class="btn" name='addentry' value="Add Record">
        </div>

Comment: Thank you for the answer I appreciate it!  I was reading an article the other day about using javascript or PHP to "submit" my button choices, I guess some it soaked in. lol